# Inner Joining 3 Tables to get a Result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL, but I am trying to find all the jobs that Monica (applicant A2) has ALL the skills for (which would be Job ID jo3 and j05.)

This is the script I am using in Oracle:

```
drop table Jobskills;
drop table Appskills;
drop table Applies;
drop table Applicant;
drop table Skills;
drop table Job;
drop table Company;

create table Company(compid char(5) primary key, compname varchar(20), 
                     comptype varchar(15));
create table Job(jobid char(5) primary key, jobtitle varchar(20),
                 salarylow int, salaryhigh int, location char(10), 
                 compid references Company(compid) on delete cascade);
create table Skills(skillid char(5) primary key, skillname varchar(15));
create table Jobskills(jobid references Job(jobid) on delete cascade, 
                       skillid references Skills(skillid), 
               expertiseneeded int, primary key(jobid,skillid));
create table Applicant(appid char(5) primary key, name varchar(15), 
                       age int, highdegree char(5), expected_salary int) ;
create table AppSkills(appid references Applicant(appid) on delete cascade, 
                       skillid references Skills(skillid), expertise int,
                       primary key(appid, skillid));
create table Applies(jobid references Job(jobid), 
                     appid references Applicant(appid) on delete cascade, 
                     appdate date, decisiondate date, outcome char(10),  
                     primary key(jobid, appid));

rem Initial Company data
insert into Company values('PWC', 'Price Waterhouse', 'consulting');
insert into Company values('MSFT', 'Microsoft', 'software');
insert into Company values('INTL', 'Intel', 'electronics');
insert into Company values('NCR', 'NCR Corp', 'server');
insert into Company values('WPAF', 'WP Air Force', 'defense');
insert into Company values('DLT', 'Deloitte', 'consulting');

rem Initial Job data
insert into Job values('101', 'Programmer', 55000, 60000, 'Redmond', 'MSFT');
insert into Job values('j02', 'Designer', 42000, 45000, 'Redmond', 'MSFT');
insert into Job values('j03', 'SAP impl', 30000, 40000, 'Chicago', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j04', 'Proj mgmt', 35000, 55000, 'Chicago', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j05', 'SOX', 60000, 65000, 'Detroit', 'PWC');
insert into Job values('j06', 'db admin', 45000, 50000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j07', 'db designer', 35000, 40000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j08', 'intern', 25000, 28000, 'Dayton', 'NCR');
insert into Job values('j09', 'engineer', 52000, 55000, 'Dayton','WPAF');
insert into Job values('j10', 'dba', 62000, 65000, 'Dayton','WPAF');
insert into Job values('j11', 'hardware dev', 50000, 65000, 'NYC','INTL');
insert into Job values('j12', 'pcb designer', 55000, 68000,'NYC','INTL');
insert into Job values('j13', 'chip designer', 40000, 55000,'Chicago','INTL');
insert into Job values('j14', 'IT', 40000, 60000, 'Dayton', 'DLT');
insert into Job values('j15', 'IT', 50000, 70000, 'Chicago', 'DLT');

rem initial Skills data
insert into Skills values('s1', 'database');
insert into Skills values('s2', 'programming');
insert into Skills values('s3', 'sox');
insert into Skills values('s4', 'project');
insert into Skills values('s5', 'hardware');
insert into Skills values('s6', 'sap');
insert into Skills values('s7', 'analysis');

rem Initial Jobskills data
insert into Jobskills values('101', 's2', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('101', 's7', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j02', 's2', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j02', 's7', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j03', 's6', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's7', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's4', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j04', 's2', 2);
insert into Jobskills values('j05', 's3', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j06', 's1', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j06', 's2', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j07', 's1', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j07', 's7', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j08', 's1', 2);
insert into Jobskills values('j09', 's2', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j09', 's4', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j10', 's4', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j10', 's1', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j11', 's5', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j11', 's4', 3);
insert into Jobskills values('j12', 's5', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j13', 's1', 4);
insert into Jobskills values('j13', 's2', 5);
insert into Jobskills values('j14', 's7', 4);

rem initial Applicants data
insert into Applicant values('a1', 'Joe', 30, 'MS', 55000);
insert into Applicant values('a2', 'Monica', 25, 'BS', 62000);
insert into Applicant values('a3', 'Jim', 22, 'BS', 45000);
insert into Applicant values('a4', 'Monica', 25, 'BS', 34000);

rem initial Appskills data
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's1', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's2', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's4', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's6', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a1', 's7', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's2', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's3', 5);
insert into Appskills values('a2', 's6', 4);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's4', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's1', 3);
insert into Appskills values('a3', 's2', 5);

rem Applies
insert into Applies values ('101', 'a1', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('101', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j02', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j04', 'a2', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'hire');
insert into Applies values ('j02', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
insert into Applies values ('j04', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
insert into Applies values ('j06', 'a3', '01-JAN-06', '08-JAN-06', 'nohire');
```

This is my code so far:

```
SELECT js.jobid
FROM jobskills js INNER JOIN appskills apps 
ON (js.skillid = apps.skillid) INNER JOIN applicant app 
ON (apps.appid = app.appid)
WHERE app.name = 'Monica'
    AND js.skillid = apps.skillid
    AND js.expertiseneeded = apps.expertise
```

I keep trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong - so anyone has an explanation that can help me figure it out it would be great! I do not want anyone to write the code for me.

This is the output I get:

```
JOBID
j02  
j05  
j06
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Error_2646 I get no error. My output is just not what I am looking for. I am going to include the output I get in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs for Monica with all the skills needed and when expertise needed is matched with skills.

```
select distinct jobid from appskills apps inner join applicant app on apps.appid=app.appid 
    inner join jobskills js on apps.skillid=js.skillid where app.name='Monica'
    and not exists (select jobid from jobskills j where js.jobid=j.jobid and js.skillid<>j.skillid)
and js.expertiseneeded=apps.expertise
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you for your help :) can you help me with the last one that is a bit more tricky? **Find all the matching pairs of jobs and applicants. An applicant  "matches" a job if and only if he/she has all the skills for the job at an equal or higher level.** So Applicant A1 would have the skills for the job: j08, j09, j14. Applicant A2 would have the skills for the job: j05. Applicant A3 would have the skills for the job: j08.

Comment: This is what I have so far. I am only missing one of applicant a1 jobs which is j09. `SELECT jobid, app.name, app.appid
FROM appskills apps INNER JOIN applicant app ON apps.appid = app.appid INNER JOIN jobskills js ON apps.skillid = js.skillid
WHERE apps.expertise >= js.expertiseneeded
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT jobid, app.name
FROM jobskills j
WHERE js.jobid = j.jobid
    AND js.skillid <> j.skillid
    AND apps.expertise >= js.expertiseneeded);`

Comment: Ok. Is there another question for it or I might answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude jobs for which Monica has partial skills.

```
 select distinct jobid from appskills apps inner join applicant app on apps.appid=app.appid 
    inner join jobskills js on apps.skillid=js.skillid where app.name='Monica'
    and not exists (select jobid from jobskills j where js.jobid=j.jobid and js.skillid<>j.skillid)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I see what you did. I have done in my class before something similar but we did `NOT IN` so I wasn't even aware of `NOT EXISTS`. What would you do now if we are looking for jobs that Monica is skilled for (equal or higher expertise level) which would only be j05?

Comment: You are most welcome. Try to use Not exists instead of Not IN since if there is any null value NOT IN will mess up the situation.

Comment: Great, that's great info - thank you for that! I wanted to ask you another question similar to this one I posted. **What would you do now if we are looking for jobs that Monica is skilled for (equal or higher expertise level) which would only be j05?**

Comment: Monica is skilled for j03 and j05. So both jobs shojld be the answer I think.

Comment: Well, j03 has the expertise of 5 needed and Monica's expertise on that is a 4. So the only job ID I see that she qualifies for both is j05

Comment: you are absolutely right. Didn't considered the expertise level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230147/discussion-between-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-and-marce).